# jQuery onload function is not work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have tried this example and doest work especially in img.onload
where is the problem here

after edited and remove () from  img.load()

```
function displayPreview(files)
{ var file = files[0];
 var img = new Image();
 var sizeKB = file.size / 1024;
 img.onload = function(){ 
 alert("Size: " + sizeKB + "KB\nWidth: " + img.width + "\nHeight: "+  img.height); 
  alert("image is loaded"); } 
 img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
 }
```

Comment: Where is the function displayPreview() called?

Comment: the problem solved and displayPreview() called in html element <input type='file' id='file_browse' name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  onchange="displayPreview(this.files);"  />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `()` after `img.onload`, When you use `()` with function name you are invoking it. You need to define the `onload` function

EDIT:

You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API.

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer.

Its method [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

> The `readAsDataURL` method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File.

Note: It works in Modern browsers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#file').change(function(e) {

    var file = this.files[0];
    var sizeKB = file.size / 1024;

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      alert("Size: " + sizeKB + "KB\nWidth: " + img.width + "\nHeight: " + img.height);
    }


    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imagedisplay').attr('src', e.target.result);
      img.src = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<img id="imagedisplay" src="" />
```

Comment: i edited it but img.onload does not work because i used alert(); function before it and the inside one .before one execute but the inside one don`t execute at all

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` after `img.onload`. `()` is for *executing* a function, not assigning.

Comment: i edited it but img.onload does not work because i used alert(); function before it and the inside one .before one execute but the inside one  don`t execute at all